# Answer with negative score was deleted, causing me to lose points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

This answer was deleted (although I'm not exactly sure why...):

[A great answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199827/is-it-okay-to-upvote-someones-questions-so-i-can-speak-with-them-in-chat/199841#199841)

Anyway, that's not why I'm asking this.  I was wondering if a mod could tell me why this answer, which had a negative score, caused me to **lose** reputation when it was deleted.  Logic would dictate that when a negatively scored post gets removed, your rep should increase by that amount.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you get a couple of upvotes that result in a net reputation increase. An upvote is worth 10 points while a downvote is worth -2 points. A negatively scored post might just earn you some reputation points. That's why some people hate sympathy upvotes.

Comment: That's why I was asking a mod.  I lost 70 points on it, I'm not even sure what the math could be.  It ended up with a -5 score.  So, 10 upvotes and 15 downvotes?

Comment: Yes. That's what it was.

Comment: BTW--It doesn't take a moderator. ANy user who can see then answer and has [1000 rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) can click on the score to see the breakdown. Try it on *this* question.

Answer (score 4):

Upvotes are weighted a lot heavier than downvotes are. So as the offsetting votes build, the more deceptive the net reputation affect can be.

Consider a post with +5,-8. This will look like -3 at first glance. But it is really giving +50, -16 reputation, a net of 34. Or, as you just mentioned in a comment, +10,-15 netting 70 reputation. I am not 10k on meta so I cannot see your deleted post. If it were recently deleted, you may be able to expand the vote count and check for yourself since it was your post.

I would guess that the balance of up and downvotes is what led to your losing rep from the answer being deleted.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you mean that "Upvotes are weighted a lot heavier than **downvotes** are."

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Haha, yes that is what I meant. Thanks for catching that :)